# Change users status from active to inactive in Openam

Tags: openam, forgerock

I am not able to find any docs to change user's status to switch between active or inactive status in Openam 13 programmatically. Is there any API exposed to do so?

Answer (score 0):

There is a REST API where you can change user status from Active to Inactive.

Authenticate as an admin user; you must use the actual AM server URL

```
$ curl -X POST -H "X-OpenAM-Username: amadmin" -H "X-OpenAM-Password: cangetinam" -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://host1.example.com:8080/openam/json/authenticate
```

Example response

```
{ "tokenId": "AQIC5wM2LY4SfcxsuvGEjcsppDSFR8H8DYBSouTtz3m64PI.*AAJTSQACMDIAAlNLABQtNTQwMTU3NzgxODI0NzE3OTIwNAEwNDU2NjE0*", "successUrl": "/openam/console", "realm": "/" }
```

Active/Inactive user account status(in this example, demo )where the iPlanetDirectoryPro header (default AM session cookie name) is set to the token returned when you authenticated:

```
$ curl -X PUT -H "iPlanetDirectoryPro: AQIC5wM2LY4Sfcxs...EwNDU2NjE0*" -H "Content-type: application/json" -d'{
    "inetUserStatus": "Active"
}' http://host1.example.com:8080/openam/json/users/demo
```

The response should have user whole hierarchy.